# Render several views that belongs to different modules in one region

Tags: marionette

I need to render two views in region App.mainRegion.
The first view belongs to the Module A, the second to module B.

What is the best approach for this ?
Some module C, should render layout.
Then Module C using request/response receive view1 and view2 and append views to layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of Marionette's strong suits is deeply nested views which is probably what you're getting at here. I think the best approach is to pass a [Marionette Layout](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md) to `app.mainRegion.show()` which contains two regions which would then show View A and View B respectively.

A quick note on `.show()` is that you only want to call it in the `.onShow()` method (rather than `initialize()` or `onRender()` or else you'll set yourself up for accessing DOM element sadness later (see [my post on this](http://averycodes.com/proper-and-improper-uses-of-marionettes-onshow-and-onrender/))

Comment: As an addendum, if you're using Marionette 1.8 you can leverage [onDomRefresh](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-domrefresh--ondomrefresh-event) to eliminate DOM access sadness.